# Catching on with JS Objects

Tags: javascript, object, scope

guys!

I'm giving my firsts steps in JS and in OOP in general, and I am trying to build code perhaps too stilized for my level, but I would like my sets and gets to be like "object.a" and "object.a = value" and not call them "getA" and "setA" and, above all, definitively not like a function ("object.a()" and "object.a(value)").

I design this page to find my way of doing but it is driving me crazy:

1. I don't know why "wa" keeps on incrementing it's value till it flips out with the message "too much recursion".
2. I don't see how to do for get a and set a to see "a" inside of "coso".

Can anybody help me?

Here's my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
</style>

<script>
    function coso() {
        var a = 1024;

        coso.prototype = {
            get a() {return this.a},
            set a(valor) {this.a = valor}
        }

        this.muestraA = function() {if(a === this.a) {alert("¡Yupi!")} else alert("A vale: " + a +", pero a vale: " + this.a)}
    }

    function GuardaA(valor) {
        var obj = new coso();

        obj.a = valor;

        obj.muestraA();

        return obj.a;
    }
</script>
<title>Prueba Objeto</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Prueba Objeto</h1>
     <form onchange="x.value=GuardaA(wa.value)">
         <label for="wa">Valor para A</label>
        <input type="number" id="wa">
         <label for="x">A vale:</label>
        <output id="x" for="wa"></output>
    </form> 
  <footer></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `var a` is not the same thing as `this.a`.

Comment: You're getting infinite recursion because `this.a` calls `get a()`, which tries to read `this.a`, which calls `get a()`, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting infinite recursion because the `get a()` function tries to read `this.a`. But `this` is the object that has the `get a()` function, so it calls that function again, and so on repeatedly.

You should be accessing the local variable `a`, because the whole point of defining a getter and setter is because you want to use that variable instead of a regular property.

```
function coso() {
    var a = 1024;

    coso.prototype = {
        get a() {return a;},
        set a(valor) {a = valor;}
    }

    this.muestraA = function() {
        if(a === this.a) {
            alert("¡Yupi!");
        } else {
            alert("A vale: " + a +", pero a vale: " + this.a);
        }
    }
}
```